# Protractor ElementArrayFinder.filter() running only once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, webdriverjs

I am having trouble with filtering a ElementArrayFinder of `<tr>` elements more than once in my page object. The second filter is being called right after the first one. In the following code, I am first verifying that a number is in the table, and then filtering it again to click on it. The reason i don't just combine these is because they are in functions that rely on the parameter batchNumber of the function, and could be different.

Filter:

```
function verifyBatchInList(batchNumber){
    BATCH_LIST_TABLE.filter(function(elem, i){
        return elem.element(by.xpath('./td[1]')).getText().then(function(text){
            text = text.trim();
            return text === batchNumber;
        });
    }).then(function(results){
        if(results.length < 1){
            throw new Error('Could not find batch "'+batchNumber+'" in batch list');
        }
    });
}
function editBatch(batchNumber){
    selectBatch(batchNumber);
    EDIT_BUTTON.click(); //this never happens
}
function selectBatch(batchNumber){
    BATCH_LIST_TABLE.filter(function(elem, i){ //this function never runs
        return elem.element(by.xpath('./td[1]')).getText().then(function(text){
            text = text.trim();
            return batchNumber === text;
        });
    }).then(function(results){ //this never runs either
        if(results.length < 1){
            throw new Error('Could not find batch "'+batchNumber+'" in batch list');
        }
        results[0].click();
    });
```

When i put a breakpoint inside of the filter function, it only gets there the first iteration, but not the second. The spec running it looks like this.

```
it('can commit batch', function(){
    page.addSpecimens.getBatchId().then(function(text){
        batchIds[0] = text.split(' ')[0];
        page.addSpecimens.commitBatch();
        page = new pages.batchList();
        browser.sleep(2000); //for page to load, just temporary
        page.verifyBatchInList(batchIds[0]); //this works fine
    });
});
it('can edit batch',function(){
    page.editBatch(batchIds[0]); //this runs, but never actually filters
});
```

The html is just a table with the first td being the batch number.

Comment: Is `batchIds` an array? Is it initialized as an empty array before each spec? I am pointing towards the idea that in your second spec `batchIds[0]` holds `undefined`.

Comment: no, batchids is defined outside the two functions, it is not undefined

Comment: i think the issue lies in the editBatch and Commit Batch function because i remove the first filter and it still has issues

Comment: i figured out that the issue is elsewhere. Abandoning this issue